# How to remove "Home" from breadcrumb wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, breadcrumbs

I have this wordpress breadcrumb code that I'm trying to edit for nested pages. I don't want the Home link to show up in the breadcrumbs.

```
<div id="crumbsOnly">

        <?php

        breadcrumbs_plus(array(

            'prefix' => '<div id="breadcrumbs">',

            'suffix' => '</div>',

            'title' => false,

            //'home' => __( 'Home', 'options_front' ),

            'sep' => '&nbsp;&nbsp;&#8725;&nbsp;&nbsp;',

            'front_page' => false,

            'bold' => false,

            //'blog' => __( 'Blog', 'options_front' ),

            'echo' => true

            ));

        ?>

    </div>
```

How do I fix it so that the home link doesn't show up? I tried canceling out (//) the 'home' but it's still there. It's not from any plugin but part of Wordpress Inspired theme. I just created a new template page with the breadcrumbs as page title for nested pages.

Comment: I think you need to edit the plugin files...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of faffing about making edits to the Breadcrumbs Plus plugin code, you would probably be better off just altering the text returned by this function.

Something like this should do it (untested, but it shouldn't be difficult to get it working):

```
<div id="crumbsOnly">
<?php
  // Generate breadcrumbs markup
  $bc = breadcrumbs_plus(array(
    'prefix'     => '<div id="breadcrumbs">',
    'suffix'     => '</div>',
    'title'      => false,
    'sep'        => '&nbsp;&nbsp;&#8725;&nbsp;&nbsp;',
    'front_page' => false,
    'bold'       => false,
    'echo'       => false
  ));

  // Remove first link (to home page)
  $bc = preg_replace('/<a .*?<a /s','<a',$bc,1);
  echo $bc;
?>
</div>
```

Note the extra parameter `1` in the `preg_replace()` call, which limits the replacement to the first occurrence of the match string.

Comment: It didn't work. I even had 'home' => false, but all it did was to remove "Home" but it didn't remove the separate icon that comes after Home. You can see the results at http://susantperkins.client.sharkbiteadmin.com/practice-areas/rhode-island-criminal-defense/

Comment: @KristinaBressler Icons? What icons? Why wasn't this mentioned in the actual question? I can't find any breadcrumbs at all in the page you linked to. If your breadcrumb links consist of a text link and an icon that are both wrapped in separate `<a>` elements, then try increasing `1` to `2` in the `preg_replace()` call. But I really can't help you if you're not going to explain what you're doing.

Comment: Sorry, the theme went wacky for few hours but it's fixed now. the icon I was referring to was the forward slash ( / ).